# How do I update a variable and all subsequent variables once a certain condition is met in R?

Tags: r, time-series

Suppose I have a dataframe with timeseries data, and associated values:

| Date and Time | Value 1 | Gap in Time | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-01 12:00:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 12:05:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 12:10:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 12:15:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 13:00:00 | X | 45 | 2 |
| 2023-02-01 13:05:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 13:10:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 16:00:00 | X | 175 | 2 |
| 2023-02-01 16:05:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 16:10:00 | X | 5 | 1 |

I want to assign group nuymbers to the data where the gaps in time are less than 25 minutes. Using ifelse, I can assign groups to rows where the gap in time is less than 25 or greater than 25:

`ifelse(df$Gap < 25, 1, 2)`

But I would like to assign all subsequent observations the same group number until another gap in time greater than 25 is observed, as is follows:

| Date and Time | Value 1 | Gap in Time | Group |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-01 12:00:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 12:05:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 12:10:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 12:15:00 | X | 5 | 1 |
| 2023-02-01 13:00:00 | X | 45 | 2 |
| 2023-02-01 13:05:00 | X | 5 | 2 |
| 2023-02-01 13:10:00 | X | 5 | 2 |
| 2023-02-01 16:00:00 | X | 175 | 3 |
| 2023-02-01 16:05:00 | X | 5 | 3 |
| 2023-02-01 16:10:00 | X | 5 | 3 |

I tried doing nested `ifelse` statements, but to no avail:

```
Group <- 1
ifelse(df$Gap < 25, Group,
      ifelse(df$Gap >= 25, Group+1,
            ifelse(df$Gap[ >= 25,(Group <- Group+1), Group)
```

Updated to fix a typo.

Comment: `df$Group <-  cumsum(df[['Gap in Time']]>25) + 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df$Group <-  cumsum(df[['Gap in Time']] > 25) + 1
df
         Date and Time Value 1 Gap in Time Group
1  2023-02-01 12:00:00       X           5     1
2  2023-02-01 12:05:00       X           5     1
3  2023-02-01 12:10:00       X           5     1
4  2023-02-01 12:15:00       X           5     1
5  2023-02-01 13:00:00       X          45     2
6  2023-02-01 13:05:00       X           5     2
7  2023-02-01 13:10:00       X           5     2
8  2023-02-01 16:00:00       X         175     3
9  2023-02-01 16:05:00       X           5     3
10 2023-02-01 16:10:00       X           5     3
```